# Generating Predicted Vs Actual table using SCORE statement

Tags: validation, sas, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to build a logistic model and I have already divided the training and validation data sets.  I used the SCORE statement in order to validate the model against the validation data.  In reviewing the SAS documentation, I read the following:  "Similarly, an actual by predicted table can be created for a validation data set by using the SCORE statement which also produces a data set containing predicted probability variables and a variable (I_y, where y is the name of your response variable) containing the predicted response category. Note that the validation data set must contain the observed responses in order to produce the table."  However my code does not produce the actual by predicted table.

I have also tried an OUTMODEL and INMODEL code with similar results.

```
proc logistic data=train plots(only)=(effect oddsratio);
class Gender Geography;
model Exited(event="1") = &cat &interval / selection=stepwise clodds=pl slstay=.05 slentry=.05;
score data=valid out=churn.churn_pred_sw;
run;
```

The only warning that I receive is as follows:  WARNING: Some plots have more than 5000 observations and are suppressed.  Specify the PLOTS(MAXPOINTS=NONE) option in the PROC 
          LOGISTIC statement to display the plots.

If I remove the Plots statement, it resolves this issue but still does not produce the actual vs predicted table based on the validation set.

Comment: What happens when you try the suggestion change: `Specify the PLOTS(MAXPOINTS=NONE) option in the PROC LOGISTIC statement to display the plots.`

Comment: Also, I believe the values you want are in the churn.churn_pred_sw data set, have you verified that data set is created and has the values needed?

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of the output dataset? Don't you see a I_exited variable? This is the predicted value. You can cross this with the actual exited variable to form a confusion matrix. I think that is what the documentation actually means.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing.  Once I used PROC FREQ with the I_exited variable, it did exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.